# Having two hashtable, when deleting an item in one, it deletes in the other

Tags: c, hashtable

I implemented a hashtable and i initialize two different ones like this:

```
hashtable *active_users = create();
hashtable *inactive_users = create();
```

An element of the hashtable above looks like this:

```
typedef struct user{
    char nick[6];
    char name[26];
    int n_messages;
    bool occupied;
}user;
```

In my main program i have a function that deletes an user from `active_users` and inserts it in the `inactive_users`, the problem is when deleting the item from the `active_users`after inserting it into `inactive_users` it deletes it in both for some reason.

```
hashtable * delete_user(hashtable *active_users, hashtable *inactive_users, char *input_a){
    if(contains(active_users, input_a) != -1){
        user *tmp = get_item(active_users, input_a); //gets the user from the active_users hashtable
        if(load_factor(inactive_users)) //checks the hashtable size
            inactive_users = resize_HashTable(inactive_users); // if needed it resizes
        insert2(inactive_users, tmp); //insert in inactive_users
        print_table(inactive_users);
        printf("\n");
        delete_item(active_users, input_a); //deletes from active_users
        print_table(inactive_users);
        printf("+ user %s removed\n", input_a);
    }else{
        printf("+ user %s doesnt exist\n", input_a);
    }
    return inactive_users;
}
```

In the code above i printed the `inactive_users` hashtable after inserting the new user there and after deleting the same user from the `active_users` so you can see the problem.

`inactive_users` after inserting:

```
i: 0, nick: me, name: mig
i: 1, nick: -, name: -
i: 2, nick: -, name: -
i: 3, nick: -, name: -
i: 4, nick: -, name: -
```

`inactive_users` after deleting from `active_users`

```
i: 0, nick: -, name: -
i: 1, nick: -, name: -
i: 2, nick: -, name: -
i: 3, nick: -, name: -
i: 4, nick: -, name: -
```

To delete an item from the hashtable i simply mark its variable "occupied" as false meaning the spot is now free to use for insertion. the code:

```
void delete_item(hashtable *HashTable, char *nick){
    int position = contains(HashTable, nick);
    if(position != -1){
        HashTable[position].buckets->occupied = false;
        HashTable->elements--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`occupied` is a field of the struct `user` which you are setting to false on `delete_item`..

Instead you should set buckets to null

```
void delete_item(hashtable *HashTable, char *nick){
    int position = contains(HashTable, nick);
    if(position != -1){
        HashTable[position].buckets = null;
        HashTable->elements--;
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe i should have posted it in the question, but the bucket is defined like this: user *bucket, if i set it to null that position is set to null and i cant do that since it will mess up the "contains" method. i need to mark a position as free to use and at the same time saying there was an item there so keep searching for more after this one

Comment: Then in that case you should create a copy of user cause I assume setting occupied to false means empty

Comment: yes it means the spot is now available to use, but i am not setting it to false when transfering it to the inactive users hashtable so i dont understand why is saying its not

Comment: so i am using the pointer to a struct in two different hashtable, and when i updated it in one since its the same pointer it updates its values in the other hashtable?